# is there a way to add multiple nodes with properties in Neo4j with Cypher

Tags: merge, neo4j, nodes, cypher

I'm trying to create a reusable bit of Cypher in which i can quickly add multiple nodes if they aren't already created.
This is what I'm attempting:

```
MERGE (n:Mal_Source {IP:'123.45.543', time:'12.32.12', location:'Canada', Classifier:'IP_ADRESS',Date:'12/21/01'}),
(n:Mal_Source { IP:'123.45.542', time:'12.2.12', location:'Laos', Classifier:'IP_ADRESS',Date:'01/02/13'}),
(n:Mal_Source { IP:'123.45', time:'12.32.1', location:'Uruguay', Classifier:'IP_ADRESS',Date:'03/05/09'}),
(n:Mal_Source { IP:'123.543', time:'1.32.12', location:'Chile', Classifier:'IP_ADRESS',Date:'05/06/07'}),
(n:Mal_Source { IP:'333.45.543', time:'1212.32.12', location:'Vietnam', Classifier:'IP_ADRESS',Date:'06/05/12'}),
(n:Mal_Source { IP:'123.4555.543', time:'5512.32.12', location:'South Korea', Classifier:'IP_ADRESS',Date:'05/09/05'})
RETURN n
```

I can't figure out why it wont work though.

Comment: Instead of comma separating, split with merge ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MERGE` checks for pattern so comma seperated nodes doesnt make up a pattern. Individual nodes do make a pattern. `MERGE` doesnt automatically check for all comma separated nodes.

2 things you would have to do:

- Use separate `MERGE` for all the nodes
- Name the nodes with different aliases ie `n:Mal_Source`, `m:Mal_Source` etc

  ```
  MERGE (n:Mal_Source {IP:'123.45.543', time:'12.32.12', location:'Canada',     Classifier:'IP_ADRESS',Date:'12/21/01'})
  MERGE (m:Mal_Source { IP:'123.45.542', time:'12.2.12', location:'Laos', Classifier:'IP_ADRESS',Date:'01/02/13'})
  MERGE (o:Mal_Source { IP:'123.45', time:'12.32.1', location:'Uruguay', Classifier:'IP_ADRESS',Date:'03/05/09'})
  MERGE (p:Mal_Source { IP:'123.543', time:'1.32.12', location:'Chile', Classifier:'IP_ADRESS',Date:'05/06/07'})
  MERGE (q:Mal_Source { IP:'333.45.543', time:'1212.32.12', location:'Vietnam', Classifier:'IP_ADRESS',Date:'06/05/12'})
  MERGE (r:Mal_Source { IP:'123.4555.543', time:'5512.32.12', location:'South Korea', Classifier:'IP_ADRESS',Date:'05/09/05'}) 
  RETURN n,m,o,p,q,r
  ```

Comment: Thanks @Sumeet! Would it make more sense then to use create instead of Merge? I'm building this to support fast queries, so would using different aliases limit that ability if I have to match on those aliases?

Comment: creating through merge will gurantee uniqueness of the node pattern and aliases are not permanent like if you again run MATCH query for say n,m nodes of the above cypher query then you can use different aliases like n1,n2 . The performance will depend on the graph design and how smart your match query will be and of course on indexing